# netbeans oracle 12c occi windows

Tags: c++, oracle, netbeans, oracle12c

I'm using netbeans 8.0 on Windows 7 x64 and trying to connect to oracle 12.1 using occi. I've downloaded 12.1.0.2.0 Oracle Instant Client for Windows x64 Basic+SDK. Installed it just unzipping to D:\instantclient_12_1. And then added this path into Windows Path variable.
Netbeans is using mingw64 compiler
In project properties in Make>compiler C++ category for include catalog(-I) D:/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include
In linker addiational libraries(-L) catalog is D:/instantclient_12_1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <occi.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace oracle::occi;
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
    Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);

    return 0;
}
```

But during making project I get:

```
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW_64-Windows/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/MinGW_64-Windows/main.o 
build/Debug/MinGW_64-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned long long), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned long long), void (*)(void*, void*))'
C:\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Environment::terminateEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_64-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I tried to add libraries "oraociei12.dll", "oraocci12d.dll"(in Debug mode), "oraocci12.dll", "orannzsbb12.dll", "oci.dll" with -l option but without changes.
What's wrong?

Comment: have you resolved this problem?

Comment: No :( But problem is not actual for me now, this project was killed)